# Swing, Eclipse RCP or which way to go?

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, eclipse-rcp

I'm a developing primary Java webapplications at work. I would like to start creating a little java desktop app. It should be a simple CRUD app with database connection, 2 - 3 forms and a smart stats page. To be honest: I'm kinda lost in this topic. I've took some time to guide through swing but the tutorials are all old and most of the stuff seems to be very unhandy. Aren't there any swing frameworks or somethingelse?

[Vogella](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) gives a good introduction into Eclipse RCP development but this all seems too much for my use at home.

What I'm searching is a easy/light way to create a desktop app. Which options are available in this topic? Would be glad if someone could share some experiences with Swing or Eclipse RCP and if its worth to spend time into getting in of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For a simple application like yours, Eclipse RCP is just overkill. Its a very high level framework. SWT is a good option. If you have any experience with Swing or SWT, I suggest you stick to it. You should also look into [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: This is what I felt like too. Its too much - I don't need a modular high stack framework. MiGLayout looks good, I'll look into

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) try [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org).

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX). I haven't yet had time to try it myself, but I hear good things about the ease of use and capabilities.

Comment: Really? So far I have heard absolutely nothing good about it.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse RCP is quite straightforward IMHO, you could always start with a Mail Template from the new Project Wizard. If youre looking for sth a little bit more lighweight you could try [Spring Application Framework](http://blog.springsource.com/2008/04/30/introducing-the-springsource-application-platform/). e4 makes it considerably easier to develop RCP "on the fast lane". You could try this excellent [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseE4/article.html)

Comment: Words of warning: Development of Spring RCP has been sluggish and at one point it was almost completely stopped. It looked promising, but there has been no new releases in a while, so I'm not sure what the current status is. The documentation is also very sparse so you probably need to dig in to the source code (which can be quite complex). On the plus side, RCP seems stable, I'm not sure if I have found a single bug during the 3+ years I have been using it.

Answer (score 2):

I am in the process of porting my Swing database application to the Netbeans RCP Platform.

The Netbeans RCP is similar to Eclipse RCP but it is fully based on Swing (Swing ships with the JRE/JDK , so it is more platform independent).

If you are a beginner to Swing, I would certainly recommend using the Netbeans RCP because it automatically solves a lot of beginner's problems and enforces good practices. It also has some powerful GUI elements (like Outline, option-button) which are not present in plain-Swing. The netbeans.org has ample video tutorials to get started.

Also, with the Netbeans RCP, you get some extra goodies which may come useful, like modular JavaHelp integration for online help in the client.

Also, Netbeans can generate easily deployable Webstart package or platform-dependent installers for deploying the desktop app (I recommend Webstart, that is the easiest way to distribute your application, only Java needs to be installed beforehand and that is usually doable even for the dumbest of users).